# Passing Messages From Content.js To Background.js Then Back To Content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension project, I send a URL from the content.js script to the background.js script. When the background.js receives the URL it will fetch the webpage and scrape the price. I want to send the price back to content.js so it can be displayed but Every time I try to call the variable price it is undefined.

Here is the script I made.

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07SFKTLZM");
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

var price;

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message) {
        fetch(message)
        .then(function(response) {
        // When the page is loaded convert it to text
        return response.text()
        })
        .then(function(html) {

        // Initialize the DOM parser
        parser = new DOMParser();

        // Parse the text
        var document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        price = document.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerHTML;
        return price;

        })
        .catch(function(err) {  
            console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);  
        });
    }
}
```

**What I Have Tried:**

```
console.log(gotMessage());
```

and

```
console.log(price);
```

**What I keep getting**

```
undefined
```

**What I Expect In Background.js**

```
$179.00
```

**What Had Worked**

The only way I have got it to work is by using this code down below but I believe there has to be a better way.

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log(price); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Long-lived connections
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

var port = chrome.runtime.connect()
Send a message to background page
port.postMessage()

Listener for response
port.onMessage.addListener()

Answer (score 0):

1. when sending the message
   you are doing this
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07SFKTLZM");
   instead you should send it in a json format
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07SFKTLZM"});
2. you are trying to execute javascript on DOM from the background script, that's wrong.
   only the contentscript has access to the DOM.
   so this section you need to move from the background script to the contentscript

// Initialize the DOM parser
parser = new DOMParser();

```
    // Parse the text
    var document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    price = document.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerHTML;
    return price;
```